# R apply, return inputs as well as outputs

Tags: r

In R, is there a way to return a dataframe-like structure that includes the inputs as well as the outputs using an apply or lapply call?

Example:

```
input1 <- c(1:3)
input2 <- c(101:103)
apply(data.frame(input1, input2), 1, function(x) {return (x['input1'] + x['input2'])})
```

produces:

```
[1] 102 104 106
```

Is there a way to use an apply statement to create the equivalent of the following:

```
  input1 input2 output
1      1    101    102
2      2    102    104
3      3    103    106
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use base R's `transform`

```
df <- data.frame(input1, input2)
transform(df, output = apply(df, 1, function(x) x['input1'] + x['input2']))
#  input1 input2 output
#1      1    101    102
#2      2    102    104
#3      3    103    106
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `apply` here, just do

```
dat <- data.frame(input1, input2)
dat[, "output"] <- dat[, "input1"] + dat[, "input2"]
dat
#  input1 input2 output
#1      1    101    102
#2      2    102    104
#3      3    103    106
```

---

Here is a quick benchmark of the two approaches

```
# dummy data
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, replicate(1e5, dat, simplify = FALSE))

library(microbenchmark)
benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  "apply" = transform(dat2, output = apply(dat2, 1, function(x) x['input1'] + x['input2'])),
  "not-apply" = `[<-`(dat2, "output", value = dat2[, "input1"] + dat2[, "input2"]), 
  times = 50
)

autoplot(benchmark)
```

[image]

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr         min          lq        mean      median          #uq         max neval
#     apply 1422.320194 1652.910918 2208.146278 2170.704283 2659.947690 3665.780187    50
# not-apply    1.778778    1.823522    1.976408    1.900479    2.123708    2.746042    50
```

Comment: These answers also work for the question. I accepted Maurits's answer because the use of the 'apply' function enables me to perform other operations within the function, which I didn't specify in the original post, but does help the application I'm working on.